# How to rotate a GameObject around his pivot and not his center?

Tags: c#, rotation, unityscript, unity-game-engine

My goal is to **rotate the engine of a plane**.

My plane have 2 engines and is represent like this in my hierarchy :
[image: Plane Hierarchy]

If I analyze my plane **from the inspector**, here's what I get in **Center**/Global mode :
[image: Plane center global mode]

And here's the **Pivot**/Global mode :
[image: Plane pivot global mode]

If I try to rotate my engine, here's the result :
[image: Rotate engine result]

As you can see, **my engine rotate not around his pivot axis but around his center axis**. How can I make it rotate around his pivot axis ?

*The code I call to make it rotate* :

```
foreach(Transform child in planeId_Object_Dictionnary[newPlane.Flight].transform){

           if (child.name == "Engine"){
                     child.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 30, 0) * Time.deltaTime*100, Space.Self);
           }
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to use a 3D software like Maya?

Comment: Not really, the object i've got here is generate by 3DSMax but not by myself and then imported in unity.

Comment: Ok. Do you have 3DSMax installed on your computer? Even if you are a game programmer, you should have Blender, 3DSMax or Maya installed on your computer when working with Unity.

Comment: Yes I have it, do you think the problem come from the original file ?

Comment: Hey Evans.  What you're looking for is the incredibly handy **RotateAround** call.  Enjoy.

Comment: Additionally, yes, it's absolutely essential to be able to "re-center" models, for use in game engineering.  It's completely commonplace that models come from your art department, with centers in the wrong place: quite simply, it **has to be fixed**.  The other classic problem is failing to have z-forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Pivot point of the 3D model is **not centered**. Since you have 3DSMax, it is better to center the pivot point from a 3D software so that you don't need to create new dummy GameOject to be used as the center point. Watch [this](https://youtu.be/ut3GKKquQFQ?t=58) video to see how to center the pivot point. Just select the Engine and click the **Center to Object** button. You should so the-same to all the other parts of the plane. Save and re-import it to Unity again.

Your code

```
if (child.name == "Engine")
{
    child.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 30, 0) * Time.deltaTime*100, Space.Self);
}
```

is not efficient. Don't compare GameObject by name. Compare it by `instance`, `instance id` or by `tag`. In your case, `tag` is appropriate.

Create a new tag in the Editor and name it **Engine**. Select all the **Engine** model parts then change their `tags` to Engine. Now, you can use the code below which is more efficient and does not allocate memory.

```
if (child.CompareTag("Engine"))
{
    child.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 30, 0) * Time.deltaTime * 100, Space.Self);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You create a empty gameobject and place it at where you want to rotate. The thing you want to rotate, make child of that empty gameobject. Now rotate that game object.

```
transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 30, 0) * Time.deltaTime*100, Space.Self);
```

This will make object rotate.

Comment: Well, how can I place this empty game object ? Because the only thing I know is the position and the localposition of my engine, and the empty gmeobject will be set surely on the center axis, so won't change my issue.

Comment: This is an extremely unfortunate workaround. Don't do this!  Go ahead and have the model fixed.  Note though that in sort of related situations, you should know and use RotateAround.